# Can not find gems running "ruby <my_script>.rb" – but works in IRB

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require, irb

I am experiencing issues when I am trying to run my .rb-file with the Ruby-command trying to access a gem. The gem i am trying to use is [Ruby-Whois](http://www.ruby-whois.org/). I have an example script below that when I try to execute it through "ruby whois.rb" I get this error message:

./whois.rb:6: uninitialized constant Whois (NameError)

However, if I run the same script line by line in IRB I get the expected result. What may cause this?

Below is **whois.rb**

```
require "rubygems"
require "whois"

domain = "google.com"

c = Whois::Client.new
a = c.query(domain)

puts a
```

Comment: Are you running the same version of ruby for the `ruby` executable and the `irb` executable?

Comment: @johusman I have no idea. How can I check? which gives me:

bash-3.2$ which irb
/usr/bin/irb
bash-3.2$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

Comment: To answer your question: those are probably symlinks. Try `readlink -f $(which irb)` and `readlink -f $(which ruby)`. But I believe @jmatraszek may be on to something in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change the name of your file - there is ambiguity in `require 'whois'` and ruby is requireing your file instead of a gem. when you do it line by line in irb ruby knows what you exactly want to require, so everything works.

Comment: Sweet that was it! Never thought it would be looking for my own whois.rb when requiring whois. Thanks alot!